# rename apache server to something other than current machine dns name

Tags: apache, url, dns

I am looking to host an intranet on one of our companies preexisting terminal servers.
The server in question will be a windows 2003 server, called ts-37 and will be running the latest version of apache.

The tests that I have performed on my own pc have allowed me to browse to this intranet, either by using http://localhost, or http://PCNAME/.

Obviously I would like our staff to have something easy to remember, such as http://intranet/ and was wondering how to do this.

As far as I can tell, they would have to browse to http://ts-37?

Thanks very much
Eds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need dns to do this, dns tells your browser that localhost and PCNAME are your apache server, so add another dns record to point to your sever when intranet is the address.

In windows 2003 server you would open up your dns manager (if your using this server as a dns server) and add a new forward lookup zone, call the zone intranet.com (or whatever) and add a new host (A) record pointing to the servers ip